Why is this oven wired this way?
In the process of removing my father's old wall oven, I noticed it was wired as shown in the images. I was expecting to see a much simpler wiring setup. Is this combining two 120s to make a 240? Are the twisted gray/silver wires a ground and is this commonly seen? Any informative comments on this wiring setup would be appreciated. I assume this may not be up to code. I have a book from Black and Decker "The Complete Guide to Wiring", but I didn't see anything helpful in understanding this wiring setup.
Edit 1: Added images from the new oven manual. It appears that it only needs 240 and doesn't require a neutral.
Edit 2: Added additional image of conduit after removing wires to oven. The black wire from the gray insulated conduit was connected with the white wire from the black insulated conduit and the red wire to the oven. The ground wires from both the gray and black insulated conduit were connected to the white and ground to the oven. The red wire (the red color is hard to see in the picture) from the gray insulated conduit was connected to the black wire from the black insulated conduit and the black to the oven.
Edit 3: 120V measured at the gray conduit. Only some phantom voltage measured at the black conduit. Not sure why the black conduit wires were in use.






Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
